# How to access alias in different test?

Tags: cypress, cypress-intercept

I have an alias defined in 1 test and I would like to use the result in a different test:

```
it('fills in the login form', () => {
    cy.intercept({
        method: 'POST',
        url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/api/v1/user/login`,
    }).as('login');
    cy.get('[data-cy="inputEmailAddress"]').type(company.users[0].email);
    cy.get('[data-cy="inputPassword"]').type(company.users[0].password);
    cy.get('[data-cy="buttonLogin"]').click();
});

it('does stuff', () => {
    cy.get('@login')
        .its('response')
        .then((res) => {
            expect(res.statusCode).to.eq(200);
        });
});
```

But I'm getting an error:

> cy.get() could not find a registered alias for: @login. You have not aliased anything yet.

Any suggestions on how to make the alias available in a different test?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use an alias across tests, Cypress clears them to keep state clean.

However it's just javascript  - **closure variables** can be used.

```js
let login;

it('fills in the login form', () => {
    cy.intercept(...)
      .then(interception => login = interception);
    ... 
});

it('does stuff', () => {

    cy.wrap(login)
      .its('response')
      .then((res) => {
          expect(res.statusCode).to.eq(200);
      });
});
```

#### Shared context

Also, the `.as('login')` command set's a variable on the Mocha context (same name as alias) which is **not cleared between tests**.

```js
it('fills in the login form', () => {
    cy.intercept(...)
      .as('login');
    ... 
});

it('does stuff', function() {    // function syntax to access "this" scope

    cy.wrap(this.login)          // access persistent scoped variable
      .its('response')
      .then((res) => {
          expect(res.statusCode).to.eq(200);
      });
});
```

Comment: the first is bad practice according to the docs https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Aliases the second doesn't work for me either, this.login is undefined in the following test

Comment: `this.login` ***is*** actually defined, if you follow the code properly.

Comment: There are examples in the [cypress examples documention](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/cc13866e55bd28e1d1323ba6d498d85204f292b5/examples/fundamentals__fixtures/cypress/e2e/load-fixtures-spec.cy.js) that use **closure variables**. The advice is way out of date and should actually be removed from the docs. You will struggle to adequately explain ***why*** it used to be considered bad advice.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Cypress Docs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Sharing-Context)

> Mocha automatically shares contexts for us across all applicable hooks
> for each test. Additionally, these aliases and properties are
> automatically cleaned up after each test.

So basically at the end of each test cypress clears all the aliases. So for the above code to work, you have move the `intercept` method to `beforeEach()`. Something like:

```js
describe('Test Suite', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.intercept({
      method: 'POST',
      url: `${Cypress.env('apiURL')}/api/v1/user/login`,
    }).as('login')
  })

  it('fills in the login form', () => {
    cy.get('[data-cy="inputEmailAddress"]').type(company.users[0].email)
    cy.get('[data-cy="inputPassword"]').type(company.users[0].password)
    cy.get('[data-cy="buttonLogin"]').click()
  })

  it('does stuff', () => {
    cy.get('@login')
      .its('response')
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.statusCode).to.eq(200)
      })
  })
})
```